# How can I change a Study to a Strategy?

Tags: pine-script

I am very new to pine script and just started yesterday trying to understand how this works.

I have copied pasted a certain study from Tradingview and now am trying to adjust to make it into a strategy.

Also another question, I also want the plotshape lines of code to be ploted directly onto the main chart instead of the window.

So two things, adding what needs to be added to change from a study to a strategy, and moving the last two plotshape lines of code from window to main chart.

Thanks

Here's the code I'm working with.

````
strategy("RSI + BB (EMA)", overlay=true)

// Инициализация параметров
src = input(title="Source", type=source, defval=close)
for_rsi = input(title="RSI_period", type=integer, defval=14)
for_ma = input(title="Basis_BB", type=integer, defval=20)
for_mult = input(title="Stdev", type=integer, defval=2, minval=1, maxval=5)
for_sigma = input(title="Dispersion", type=float, defval=0.1, minval=0.01, maxval=1)

// Условия работы скрипта
current_rsi = rsi(src, for_rsi)
basis = ema(current_rsi, for_ma)
dev = for_mult * stdev(current_rsi, for_ma)
upper = basis + dev
lower = basis - dev
disp_up = basis + ((upper - lower) * for_sigma)
disp_down = basis - ((upper - lower) * for_sigma) 
color_rsi = current_rsi >= disp_up ? lime : current_rsi <= disp_down ? red : #ffea00

// Дополнительные линии и заливка для областей для RSI
h1 = hline(70, color=#d4d4d4, linestyle=dotted, linewidth=1)
h2 = hline(30, color=#d4d4d4, linestyle=dotted, linewidth=1)
fill (h1, h2, transp=95)

// Алерты и условия срабатывания
rsi_Green = crossover(current_rsi, disp_up)
rsi_Red = crossunder(current_rsi, disp_down)

alertcondition(condition=rsi_Green, 
     title="RSI cross Above Dispersion Area",
     message="The RSI line closing crossed above the Dispersion area.")

alertcondition(condition=rsi_Red,
     title="RSI cross Under Dispersion Area",
     message="The RSI line closing crossed below the Dispersion area")

// Результаты и покраска
plot(basis, color=black)
plot(upper, color=#00fff0, linewidth=2)
plot(lower, color=#00fff0, linewidth=2)
s1 = plot(disp_up, color=white)
s2 = plot(disp_down, color=white)
fill(s1, s2, color=white, transp=80)
plot(current_rsi, color=color_rsi, linewidth=2)
plotshape(rsi_Green, title="RSI Buy Signal", location=location.belowbar, color=green, transp=0, style=shape.triangleup, text="Buy")
plotshape(rsi_Red, title="RSI Sell Signal", location=location.abovebar, color=red, transp=0, style=shape.triangledown, text="Sell") ```
````

Answer (score 1):

A script is a considered a study in TradingView if it begins with the function "study()", while strategies always begin with the function "strategy()".

For example, inserting the function with the following arguments will define your strategy's name, and setting overlay to true will add it to the main chart instead of displaying in a separate indicator chart at the bottom.

```
strategy(title='MyStudy', overlay=true)
```

If you're changing the overlay from false to true in your script, remember to remove the existing one in the chart, and then adding again; otherwise, the plot may not refresh.

The difference between study and strategy is that a strategy script typically contains functions such as strategy.entry() and strategy.exit() that tell the engine when to buy and sell, while a study merely plots data in the chart.

Your script is already defined as a strategy. All you need to do is add the necessary strategy.entry() and strategy.exit() lines to implement your strategy, and plot the lines that you want to be displayed.